# React Native Navigation Experimental Tab Switch Unmount/WillMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Our React Native app uses Navigation Experimental NavigationCardStack. On switch tab (NavigationStateUtils.jumpToIndex), the scenes in the tab I switch from, unmount. When I switch back to the original tab, the same scenes mount again causing some slowness in the app.

We've created an example GitHub repo here: https://github.com/zachrnolan/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example/tree/tabs

Is this behavior part of Navigation Experimental or a side-effect of our navigation implementation?

Comment: IDK why you're using a navigator for tabs. This should be handled by a single "scene".

Comment: @Eldelshell - Thanks for the reply. I'm not exactly sure how most people handle this. We started our app based on the [Pepperoni app kit](https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit) and that is how they implemented navigation experimental with tabs. Are you aware of any other public projects that handle the tabs the way you are suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you didn't switch tabs, you replaced the navigation states. To actually switch tabs, you should pass `tabs` state to `NavigationCardStack` like this (fixed code from you sample):

```
<NavigationCardStack
  navigationState={tabs}
  onNavigateBack={backAction}
```

But if I understand correctly and you want to keep page navigation, do so by splitting navigation pattern in two and nest one to another. For ex:

- `<TabsContainer>` - controls tabs navigation and renders Tab1 or Tab2 (it should not draw header!). Uses state.tabNavigationState
- `<Tab1>` - controls page navigation, draws header and renders Page1A and Page1B. Uses state.pageNavigationState
- `<Tab2>` - renders `Page2` (without navigation for example, but it can contain anything)